# Probability on a chess board

Tags: probability

Two squares are chosen at random from a chess board . What is the probability that the two squares chosen have exactly one corner in common ? [image: please refer to the picture]

According to my reasoning , if we consider one of the longest diagonals consisting of $8$ squares , we get $7$ such pairs that have one corner in common. If we then move back towards the next diagonal consisting of $7$ squares we get $6$ such pairs. Then continuing in this manner ,we come to the smallest diagonal consisting of two squares in which one pair is formed. This gives us

$7+6+5+4+3+2+1= 28$ such pairs for one half of the chess board . We can continue in a similar manner for the other half and we will get the same answer. Hence the total number of such squares is $(2)(28)=56$ squares.

According to me the probability should be $\dfrac{56}{\binom{64}{2}}= 0.02$ but the actual answer is $0.04$. Can you please help me to find my mistake ? 
Thank you !

Comment: What about pairs on the diagonals going the other way?

Comment: @Alessandro That’s why I multiplied it by 2

Comment: I think I must’ve forgotten the 12 squares between the two main diagonals

Comment: Also, $\frac{56}{\binom{64}{2}}=\frac{1}{36}$, not $0.02$.

Comment: @Noble yes I just thought of expressing it in a decimal form

Comment: @Aditi You didn't even round it correctly, though. $\frac{1}{36}=0.027777....$, which is about $0.03$.

Comment: @Noble I’m sorry

Comment: I genuinely think I must’ve forgotten the $12$ squares between the two main diagonals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at the diagonals going from top-left to bottom-right. There is one big diagonal which is $8$ squares long, giving us $7$ pairs. Then, there are $2$ diagonals which are $7$ squares long on either side of the big diagonal, each giving us $6$ pairs. On the other sides of those diagonals, there are $2$ diagonals which are $6$ squares long, each giving us $5$ pairs. This pattern continues until we get $2$ diagonals which are $2$ squares long, each giving us $1$ pair. Thus, the number of pairs for all of the top-left to bottom-right diagonals is:

$$7+2*6+2*5+...+2*1=49$$

Now, look at the diagonals going from top-right to bottom-left. The analysis is exactly the same, except the diagonals are just going in a different direction. Thus, these diagonals give us another $49$ pairs.

Therefore, the total number of pairs is $98$ and the answer is:

$$\frac{98}{\binom{64}{2}}=\frac{7}{144}$$

Comment: Right ! I forgot to count diagonals on both sides of the main diagonal ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Sample space is $\dbinom{64}{2}$ because we are choosing $2$ squares out of total $64$ squares.

We have $7$ unique adjacent squares in each row and column.

So, the possible cases are $7\times(8\mbox{ row } + 8\mbox{ columns })=112$

So, the required probability is $=\left(\dfrac{\mbox{possible cases}}{\mbox{ sample space}}\right)=\dfrac{112}{\dbinom{64}{2}}=\dfrac{1}{18}$

Comment: I’m sorry but the answer appears to be $\frac{7}{144}$ . However I could be wrong.

Comment: @Aditi Actually, this is the answer I got, but I was unsure since it is not equal to $0.04$. I will write my answer now.

Comment: @Aditi This answer is also correct. Note that $\dfrac{1}{18}\approx\dfrac{7}{144}$

Comment: Okay I get it now ! Thanks !